# How to increase Transaction Time Out in java (using weblogic)

Tags: java, timeout, javabeans, weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic 12.c, and writing a J2EE application.

I have a Bean in my java app, which is working a little bit long, about 5 or 10 minutes sometimes.
The weblogic **Stuck Thread Max Time** is 120.

I am wondering, is there any way to increase this number in my java application? So only this bean could use more time, other beans should use this 120.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set transaction time out param inside weblogic datasource configuraiton screen.But frankly i wouldnt suggest to do this beacause it can have negative side affects.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this tutorial.
It uses a file called ejb-j2ee-engine.xml to set the property.

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/49/0fcf14a74e740ee10000000a421937/content.htm

```
 ...
```

```
  <property>

     <property-name>session-timeout</property-name>

     <property-value>86400</property-value>

  </property>

  ...

  <property>…</property>
```